# What is Quasi-particle weight?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, definition, weight, quasiparticles

Hi I just heard this phrase from my classmate yesterday, I am wondering whether someone can explain this real quick for me.

Comment: To start with, are you familiar with the notion of a quasiparticle?

Comment: In my naive understanding, it describes a system that behaves like a particle. For instance, you can think of the transition b/w coherent states as a quasiparticle.

Comment: Are you dead sure it's "weight" and not "mass"?

Comment: yeah, weight :)

Comment: -1 Not clear. This question is lacking context, without which the meaning of the phrase is obscure. For all you know your friend might have misheard. You could try asking him.

Comment: That said, I googled your title and got as hit #4 [Extracting Quasi-particle Weight from the Imaginary Time Self-Energy](http://condensedconcepts.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/extracting-quasi-particle-weight-from.html), and as hit #5 [Notes on Quasi-Particles](http://pcteserver.mi.infn.it/~molinari/NOTES/quasiparticle.pdf) - see section D where : *Its value at the Fermi momentum measures the jump in the occupation number in spin-momentum space at the Fermi value*. In the [Science Direct overview](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/quasiparticle) it is 
 the area under the Lorentzian.

Comment: +1. This seems like a common term used in the field, and it is difficult to find a definition online, so a definitive answer to this question seems like it would serve this site's purpose (i.e. an online reference for physicists) well.

Comment: @Chris Definitions are easily found in the page 1 search articles I cited. But I agree it is worthwhile having an explanation on this site, hence I retracted my close vote. My down-vote reflects the lack of basic research effort in the question - eg internet search, or asking the classmate for more information.

Comment: @sammygerbil Fair enough.

Comment: If you are certain your colleague mentioned "quasi particle weight", check with him he didn't mean "quasi particle mass" - because this is a basic concept, while the first one is unknown to me (despite a PhD in quantum physics).
The mass of a quasi particle is a way to describe interactions within an ensemble of particles. You describe the low energy excitation of such system with an parabolic dispersion relation $E\propto p^2$ and the coefficient can be interpreted as a mass. For a more detailed description, see "self'-energy".

Comment: Quasiparticle weight is a standard term in the context of condensed matter theory and is related to the Källén–Lehmann spectral representation. Probably_someone's answer has the right general idea.

Comment: @Rococo That's good, because I'm not by any means a condensed matter theorist. Feel free to improve as needed.

Answer (score 4):

In quantum field theory, the *propagator* is a correlation function between two points in momentum-space. In order to get any useful conclusions from quantum field theory (like, for example, deriving the expectation value of an operator), one must integrate over all possible paths; the propagator between the endpoints of subsections of that path plays a critical role.

One difficulty that can sometimes arise is that the propagator may not necessarily yield a finite integral. One way it can fail to converge is if it has one or more *poles* (i.e. points where it goes to infinity) at various places along the real line. These poles define quasiparticles. Fortunately, complex analysis allows us to avoid these poles by dipping slightly into the complex plane. Doing so splits the propagator into two independent parts: the *regular part*, which is the part that behaves nicely with respect to integration, and a *quasiparticle propagator* which is weighted by the residue of the pole of the original propagator. This residue is what we call the *quasiparticle weight*; it's the spectral weight of a quasiparticle with a given momentum.

By splitting the propagator in this way, we're able to turn a weakly-interacting theory into a non-interacting one, which is much easier to deal with.

Note that this property is distinct from quasiparticle mass, just as electron spectral weight is different from electron mass.